# HTML Option element with data attributes. Is it posible and if so, how to retrive value with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I just wonder if is it posible to have option elements in html with data- attributes and so, if that posible how to retrive this value.

More specific. Lets say I have the following code:

```
<select name="areas" id="areas">
    <option value="1" data-lat="12.243" data-lng="32.43242">Area name</option>
    <option value="2" data-lat="14.243" data-lng="34.43242">Area name</option>
    <option value="3" data-lat="16.243" data-lng="36.43242">Area name</option>
    <option value="4" data-lat="18.243" data-lng="38.43242">Area name</option>
</select>
```

then, is it any way to get the data-lat and data-lng for from the selected option via jQuery ?

Comment: Yes it is possible, and you'd retrieve it's value just like you would any other attribute, with the .attr method.

Comment: @KevinB - Wouldn't using `.data('lat')` and `.data('lng')` be more appropriate?

Comment: It's Gelocation data, it might not need to be a number therefore .attr could more appropriate. It just depends on what you're going to DO with the data once you get it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes that's possible.
Any attribute value can be get by:

```
$('option:selected').attr('data-lng')
```

and set by:

```
$('option:selected').attr('data-lng', 1234);
```

Comment: Why option:eq(0) ? I do not need the value from the first one but from the selected one

Comment: @MerianosNikos then select the selected one. the concept is the same.

Comment: perfect solution. I dont even know why they use onchange event instead of attributes like this?!

Answer (score 5):

Set attribute using [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.setAttribute):

```
document.getElementById('areas')
    .getElementsByTagName('option')[index]
    .setAttribute('data-lng', 'foo');
```

Get attribute using [`getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getAttribute):

```
document.getElementById('areas')
    .getElementsByTagName('option')[index]
    .getAttribute('data-lng');
```

Both get and set:

```
var el = document.getElementById('areas')
    .getElementsByTagName('option')[index];
el.getAttribute('data-lng');
el.setAttribute('data-lng', 'foo');
```

**Note 1** I have used `document.getElementById('areas').getElementsByTagName('option')[index]` because probably is more cross-browser, but you could use

- `document.getElementById('areas').getElementsByTagName('option')[index]`
- `document.getElementById('areas').options[index]`
- `document.getElementById('areas')[index]`

**Note 2** I have used `setAttribute` and `getAttribute` because they are more cross-browser, but you could also use [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.dataset):

```
el.dataset.lng;            // get
el.dataset.lng = 'foo';    // set
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to retrieve data attributes from elements

```
$('#areas options').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).data('lat'), $(this).data('lng'));
}
```

The advantage of this over [`.attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) is this is that you get type conversion so you'll get a Numeric value in this case rather than a string.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to add, If you want to target a specific `<select>`

You can also pass the container element so that `<options>` from only that element will be selected.

```
// For user with events like .on("change") etc.
console.log($("option:selected", this).attr("data-lat"));
```

OR

```
console.log($("option:selected", "#areas").attr("data-lat"));
```