# foreach() triggers 'Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded'

Tags: javascript, php, foreach

I'm in trouble with a simple php foreach wich attribute classes (odd / even) to divs. I think i have a synthax error because it works but the loop is not ended (Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded in console :

```
<?php
$count = 0;

foreach( $this->boutiques_details as $key => $value){
     if ($value->ville == $this->ville)     {

echo '<div data-lng="$this->escape($value->longitude)" data-lat=" $this->escape($value->latitude)" class="' . (++$count%2 ? "shop odd" : "shop even") . '">';
?>
        <p><b><?php echo $this->escape($value->ville)?></b></p>
        <p><?php echo $this->escape($value->quartier)?></p>
        <p><?php echo $this->escape($value->adresse)?></p>
        <p><?php echo $this->escape($value->num_contact_1)?></p>
        </div>
  <?php
        }
 }

?>
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: You're posting PHP but your error is a javascript error.

Comment: Yes but it comes from that php script. in facts, when i remove it i have no issues

Comment: No - it doesn't come from the PHP script. It might be because you have javascript/jQuery script that checks elements with the `data-lng` or `data-lat` attributes or elements with a `.shop` class, and when you remove this loop there are no such elements. If you click right to your error it shows you what line the *javascript* error is on.

Comment: Are odd/even classes you are adding just for styling or they have some other use as well? If it's only for styling, you can do that using css only (no need to add classes).

Comment: yes but css only solution with nth is not working on ie8 so that was the best solution for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some PHP code in the string you're trying to echo, but it's not being evaluated by PHP because it's inside the string:

```
echo '<div data-lng="$this->escape($value->longitude)" data-lat="$this->escape($value->latitude)" class="' . (++$count%2 ? "shop odd" : "shop even") . '">';
```

Replace the above with the following:

```
echo '<div data-lng="' . $this->escape($value->longitude) . '" data-lat="' . $this->escape($value->latitude) . '" class="' . (++$count%2 ? "shop odd" : "shop even") . '">';
```

This way, the PHP parts (such as `$this->escape($value->longitude)`) will be recognized by PHP, and their results will be inserted in the string you are `echo`ing.

Because you were `echo`ing the PHP parts directly, javascript (jQuery) probably recognized the dollar sign (`$`), tried to do something with it but didn't know how, and failed.

Comment: There must be something very weird about the javascript code on the site if fixing the attributes fixed the stack overflow problem.

Comment: That's probably because jQuery uses the dollar sign, too.

Comment: @Nic Why would jQuery randomly evaluate stuff in random attributes without being told to? [Of course it doesn't just do that by itself](http://jsfiddle.net/D2QDs/).

Comment: @h2ooooooo to be honest, I have no idea without seeing the full code, but it's the only explanation I can think of.

Comment: @Nic From what I can imagine there's an `eval(elem.attr('data-lng'))` somewhere in the code for this to happen. Not very reassuring. :)

Comment: To be honest, I'm not an expert on javascript / jQuery, but I'm guessing that jQuery does *something* with those attributes, for instance to render some kind of map, as illustrated in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19187001/1001110). And I'm guessing this might result in an error if the attribute contains an unexpected value, such as PHP code.